# RAILS: a Complex Find Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, triggers, find

Let us say we have models as such:

Trigger
belongs_to :position

Position
has_many :trigger

Position has a few fields including :posx, :poxy, and maybe few other fields we would like to filter by...

Essentially. Within the triggers_controller, I would like to find all triggers that fall within some range of posx and posy.

I've done this in one query in cakephp so I know it should be possible, but I don't know how to structure this in rails. Furthermore, I don't know how to do "and" and "or" etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a scope to handle this sort of potentially common lookup:

```
class Trigger < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :position

  # if you're in rails 2
  named_scope :within, lambda{|tlx, tly, brx, bry| {:joins => :position, conditions => ['`positions`.posx >= ? AND `positions`.posy >= ? AND `positions`.posx <= ? AND `positions`.posy <= ?', tlx, tly, brx, bry]} }

  # if you're in rails 3
  scope :within, lamba{|tlx,tly,brx,bry| joins(:position).where('`positions`.posx >= ? AND `positions`.posy >= ? AND `positions`.posx <= ? AND `positions`.posy <= ?', tlx, tly, brx, bry) }
end
```

Then in your controller you would just do:

```
Trigger.within(top_left_x, top_left_y, bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y)
```

Comment: Ahh, awesome... is it possible to have multiple within methods/symbols? Where can I find more about creating a scope?

Comment: Oh is :within just the name of the scope? Cool :)

Comment: I would download a copy of the searchable rails docs from here: [railsapi](http://railsapi.com/) then search for named_scope (rails 2) or scope (rails 3). If you're new to rails and looking for information on the query interface, syntax, and examples then pull up the docs for ActiveRecord::Base (search for Base).

Comment: Yes, :within is just the name